# How can l view files and folders of PCs connected to Active Directory in Java?

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

I am new in Java.

First of all, there is a domain and there is also a PC with windows server 2012 which have an Active directory. And through this Active Directory, all other PCs in the domain can be seen.

Now, I was given a project which I need to develop a programme that have to access files and folders in each PC seen in the Active Directory.

How can I achieve that? Which lib or API do I use. I need any idea to achieve that. I have used the DirContext in JNDI API, still I don't get.

Comment: Hint: That information isn't in Active Directory. Nothing to do with Java or JNDI.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: l have rephrased the question for better understanding of what am trying to do. Thanks